# Efficient Memory allocation and freeing question

Tags: c, c99

I am writing a program that prints a string having been removed white space.

At this time, in the `removeWhiteSpace` function, I would like to know if memory allocation and freeing are used efficiently.

If not, can you suggest appropriate improvements:

```c
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

char *removeWhiteSpace();

int main()
{
    char *inputString = malloc(sizeof(char) * 100);
    
    scanf(" %[^\n]s", inputString);
    
    removeWhiteSpace(inputString);
    
    printf("%s\n", inputString);
    
    free(inputString);
    
    return 0;
}

char *removeWhiteSpace(char *inputString)
{
    char *tempArray = malloc(sizeof(char) * 100);
    char *tempPointer = strtok(inputString, " ");
    
    while (tempPointer != NULL)
    {
        strcat(tempArray, tempPointer);
        tempPointer = strtok(NULL, " ");
    }
    
    strcpy(inputString, tempArray);
    
    free(tempArray);
    
    return tempArray;
}
```

Comment: Questions about working code are better asked on Code Review, not SO

Comment: `free(tempArray); return tempArray;` is a problem. You're returning a pointer to memory that has been freed.

Comment: There is no need for memory allocation in `removeWhiteSpace` at all. When each output element depends only on later elements in the input array, the work can be done by writing output into the same array.

Comment: Your two definitions of removeWhiteSpace do not match.  Don't ignore compiler errors or warnings.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would do a [tortoise and hare](https://wiki.c2.com/?TortoiseAndHare) algorithm.
Copy only characters that are not space.

```
char *removeWhiteSpace(char *inputString) {
    char *in = inputString;
    char *out = inputString;

    // small optimization - do not copy to itself
    while (*in != '\0' && *in != ' ') {
       in++;
       out++;
    }

    for (; *in != '\0'; in++) {
       if (*in != ' ') {
            *out++ = *in;
       }
    }
    *out = '\0';
    return inputString;
}
```

Comment: It is a shame the other (incorrect) answer is accepted and not this one.

Comment: Your `while` loop will run infinitely as it does not update its pointer position. Neither does it update the output pointer position!

Comment: It should be: `while (*in != '\0' && *in != ' ') {in++; out++;}`

Comment: Maybe best if you remove your "small optimization."

Comment: @PaulOgilvie Thank you!!! I got an error and didn't know what to do, thank you.

Comment: @PaulOgilvie `*in != '\0' &&` 
I don't know why I need this. Help...

Comment: A null character, `'\0'`, signals the end of the string. There is no text anymore, so processing should stop.

Answer (score -1):

Dynamic allocation takes some cost. Dynamically allocating such small fixed-size arrays doesn't look efficient. Also the return value of `removeWhiteSpace` is meaningless because it refers to a buffer that is already freed.

Simply allocate the arrays statically and have `removeWhiteSpace` return nothing.

Also note that:

- You should declare arguments of functions to avoid mistakes.
- You have to initialize the array `tempArray` before using `strcat` for that. Using initializer won't be efficient because it wll initialize all elements while only initializing the first element is required for `strcat()`.
- You should limit the maximum length to read via `scanf()` to avoid buffer overrun.
- You won't need `s` in the `scanf()` format because input is specified by `[` and there are no `scanf()` after that. The `s` is telling `scanf()` to consume `s` after the string.

Try this:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

void removeWhiteSpace(char*);

int main()
{
    char inputString[100];
    
    scanf(" %99[^\n]", inputString);
    
    removeWhiteSpace(inputString);
    
    printf("%s\n", inputString);
    
    return 0;
}

void removeWhiteSpace(char *inputString)
{
    char tempArray[100];
    char *tempPointer = strtok(inputString, " ");
    tempArray[0] = '\0';
    
    while (tempPointer != NULL)
    {
        strcat(tempArray, tempPointer);
        tempPointer = strtok(NULL, " ");
    }
    
    strcpy(inputString, tempArray);
}
```

Comment: having printf malloc overhead is less than marginal

Comment: Wow! Thank you MikeCAT. 
Thanks to that, I learned a lot.

Comment: `tempArray` cannot be larger than `inputString` but the latter can be larger than 100. So `char tempArray[(strlen(inputString)+1);` is better.

Comment: This is an awful code! It has fixed size array of 100, but nothing limits input string to 100 characters! I am not even talking about the fact that no intermediate array is required to solve the problem...

Comment: @goisak you could only learn bad habits from this answer.